# Unsure why my function is partially working - Click div rotate icon

Tags: javascript, css

I have written code for that when a user clicks on a div, the icon inside the div rotates 45deg. Yet, this is only working if the user clicks on the icon itself, and not anywhere around the div it is centered in. My objective is have this working if a user clicks anywhere around the div and of course if the icon itself is clicked. Any advice is always appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Array.from(toggleBtn).forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const card = event.target.closest(".director__card");
    const iconBox = event.target.closest(".director__card--iconBox");
    const icon = event.target.closest(".director__card--icon");
    card.classList.toggle("flipped");
    if (card.classList.contains("flipped")) {
      iconBox.classList.add("switched");
      icon.classList.add("rotate");
    } else {
      iconBox.classList.remove("switched");
      icon.classList.remove("rotate");
    }
  })
);
```

```
<div class="director__card">
                <div class="director__card--frontside">
                <img class="director__card--avatar" src="${card.image}" alt="director-img" />
                <h1 class="director__card--title">${card.name}</h1>
                <p class="director__card--role">${card.role}</p>
                <div class="director__card--iconBox">
                <img class="director__card--icon" src="${card.icon}" alt="icon" />
                </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

I am rendering the elements by mapping over an array of objects-

[image: if a user clicks on the icon, icon rotates]

[image: if a user clicks on the div icon is located in, it does not rotate]

Comment: you should apply onclick event listener to the icon wrapper(div) then it will work fine. I hope it will help you!

Comment: yes, (toggleBtn) is the icon wrapper ^

Comment: Without seeing the html markup, I'd agree with @GulshanAggarwal - if that isn't the answer then we need to see how the markup is put together

Comment: Yeah @Kinglish you are right!

Comment: @Kinglish I have updated my question with the html markup-

Comment: @Kinglish if you have time, can you check my most recent question